# Fastest type to use for comparing hashes in matlab

Tags: matlab, performance, hash

I have a table in Matlab with some columns representing 128 bit hashes.

I would like to match rows, to one or more rows, based on these hashes.

Currently, the hashes are represented as hexadecimal strings, and compared with `strcmp()`. Still, it takes many seconds to process the table.

**What is the fastest way to compare two hashes in matlab?**

I have tried turning them into *categorical* variables, but that is much slower. Matlab as far as I know does not have a 128 bit numerical type. *nominal* and *ordinal* types are deprecated.

Are there any others that could work?

The code below is analogous to what I am doing:

```
nodetype = { 'type1'; 'type2'; 'type1'; 'type2' };
hash = {'d285e87940fb9383ec5e983041f8d7a6'; 'd285e87940fb9383ec5e983041f8d7a6'; 'ec9add3cf0f67f443d5820708adc0485'; '5dbdfa232b5b61c8b1e8c698a64e1cc9' };

entries = table(categorical(nodetype),hash,'VariableNames',{'type','hash'});

%nodes to match. filter by type or some other way so rows don't match to
%themselves.
A = entries(entries.type=='type1',:);
B = entries(entries.type=='type2',:);

%pick a node/row with a hash to find all counterparts of
row_to_match_in_A = A(1,:);
matching_rows_in_B = B(strcmp(B.hash,row_to_match_in_A.hash),:);

% do stuff with matching rows...
disp(matching_rows_in_B);
```

The hash strings are faithful representations of what I am using, but they are not necessarily read or stored as strings in the original source. They are just converted for this purpose because its the fastest way to do the comparison.

Comment: A [mcve] may help

Comment: I think the question is pretty self-explanatory. Anyways, I don't have much to comment on this problem - could try two 64-bit doubles at best? Someone with better background in this matter can help I suppose.

Comment: It's not self explanatory... this is a MATLAB-centric problem, but it might be that 99% of MATLAB answerers here have no idea even what a "hash" looks like! You say you have a table, can you clarify that this is actually the `table` data type or just another word for matrix (jargon issues are common here). You say you're currently using `strcmp`, show us 2 hashes, how you compare them etc (even just those 3 lines of code!) so we have a concrete example of what you want to achieve. You talk about numerical types when you just mentioned comparing strings, again what are your hashes?

Answer (score 1):

Optimization is nice, *if you need it*. Try it out yourself and [*measure* the performance](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/measure-performance-of-your-program.html) gain for relevant test cases.

Some suggestions:

- Sorted arrays are easier/faster to search
- Matlab's default numbers are `double`, [but you can also construct integers](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/integers.html). Why not use 2 `uint64`'s instead of the 128bit column? First search for the upper 64bit, then for the lower; or even better: use `ismember` with the `row` option and put your hashes in rows:

  ```
    A = uint64([0 0;
                0 1;
                1 0;
                1 1;
                2 0;
                2 1]);
    srch = uint64([1 1;
                   0 1]);
    [ismatch, loc] = ismember(srch, A, 'rows')       

    > loc =
         4
         2
  ```
- Look into the compare functions you use (eg `edit ismember`) and strip out unnecessary operations (eg `sort`) and safety checks that you know in advance won't pose a problem. [Like this solution does](https://mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/92533-how-do-i-perform-a-binary-search-of-a-presorted-array). Or if you intend to call a search function multiple times, sort in advance and skip the check/sort in the search function later on.